# Selecting lens filters based on ICC or DCP profiles

Tags: film, color-management, color-correction, color-filters, expired-film

I have a shoebox full of very old 120 film and I'm experimenting around with it.
I want to try to compensate the color shift with lens filters and see what the result is.
I have made a few shots of a color checker from which I get my calibrated color profiles.
Would it be possible to take the calibration data (color profiles) and "calculate" what color filters to use?
I'm thinking about screwing 2 filters on the lens to balance out the tone, but I have no idea how to calculate for multiple filters (lee or wratten values are fine).
I know this is pretty nonsensical, but would it be possible?
The look would be pretty novel, I imagine.